# Resistor circuit problem

Tags: resistors, circuit-analysis, schematics

I am having trouble with a circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fePDF5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I must calculate the voltage across R1.My answer is to first compute the current running across R1 and R4 , the two forming a series circuit:

6V/(1k+2k)ohms=0,002A

Then I calculate the voltage drop across R1:

V1=I*R1=0,002*1000=2V

It seems that I am wrong , but I don't understand how to do it in another way.
How must I compute the voltage across R1?

Comment: Hint : Are any resisters in parallel with R1? And what is off to the right (where are those wire connected)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R1 and R2 are **NOT** in series.

Here is how you can do it:
R1, R2 and R3 are in parallel. Calculate the parallel resistance of those three resistors so you can see them as one and call it R123.

Now R123 and R4 are in series. They form a voltage divider.

Now you should be able to calculate the volatge accross R123 (which is equal to the volatge across R1).

Comment: Sorry , I meant  R1 and R4

Comment: Ok, but still you can not ignore R2 and R3. Your calculation doesn't care about R2 and R3 at all. Imagine that e.g. R3 was very small (say 0.1 Ohm). I'd have an enormous effect on the voltage across R3 (it'd be very small). And the voltage across R3 is the same as the voltage across R1.

Comment: I understand that the voltage across R123 is equal with the ones across R1 ,R2 and R3?Why is that?

Comment: If R123 is the equivalent of R1, R2 and R3 in parallel there must be the same voltage aross the terminals. Otherwise it wouldn't be equivaltent.

Comment: Ok , right , that's a law , voltage must be the same on all three branches.I didn't understand something , how can we say that the voltage on a branch is 6 volts when there is a voltage drop (voltage is modified).Shouldn't there be a substraction , until 0 is reached?

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe you mean the KVL (Kichhoffs Voltage Law): all voltages in a mesh (loop) add up to zero.

Comment: The voltage across each branch is equal , so that means that the voltage drop is also always equal,too?Can you explain this in detail?

Comment: No I can't :-) Voltage drop along a component just *is* the voltage between the terminals of the component.

Comment: Would the downvoter have to balls to tell why he thinks this answer needs a downvote?

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy question if you have a solid knowledge in basics of circuits

So These are  steps that  I will use to solve your problem,

- First find the equivalent resistance between L and M.And before that you want to ground a particular point of a circuit(this is a must because we want to find the voltage, simply we use that grounded point as the reference point. Which means we find voltage of other places with respect to that voltage. Usually we ground the **negative terminal of the battery )**

  To find the total equivalent resistance through LM , it is better to isolate those parallel resistance. Because then we can get a clear view of it
  resistance   as shown below.

[image]

So the total resistance between Land M is

[image]

- Redraw the circuit with this modification as shown below,

[image]

Now you have a simple series circuit. So for this you can use voltage divider theorem

Then you can find the potential drop through the resistor of 0.4 kiloohms resistor as ,

[image]

So this  much of voltage drop can be seen  in R1 also as it is parallel with the equivalent resistance that I found above.

Then the voltage drop through R1 is 1V

Comment: Is the voltage across the first branch of the parallel circuit equal with 6 volts?

Comment: The voltage divider theorem states that:Vout=Vin*(R2/(R1+R2)).In our case,R1=400ohms and R2=2000ohms.You wrote:Vin*(R1/(R1+R2)) thus Vout=6V*(2/5k/(2/5k+2k)) in a wrong way.The answer is 6V*(2k/(2/5k+2k)=5volts...which seems wrong.

Comment: Which branch you are talking about?

Comment: I was talking about all branches.Look at my second comment , it seems that there is something wrong with the voltage divider theorem you applied...

Comment: tell me what are the parts that you find confusing in my answer

Comment: It looks like you used the theorem in a wrong way.It would be (2/(12/5))*6V not ((2/5)/(12/5))*6V.The second resistor is 2k ohms not 2/5k ohms..

Comment: Your aim is to find the  voltage across R1. For that we want to find the voltage drop through the equivalent resistance of R1,R2 and R3. The equivalent of those are equal to (2/5)kilo ohms.I have find the voltage drop through that resistor as 1v.Since the R1 and the equivalent resistors are parallel voltage drop through equivalent equal to voltage drop through R1.

Comment: Yes,but I told you ,after redrawing the circuit with the equivalent resistor you made a mistake when using the voltage divider theorem.It should have been 2 not 2/5 there , on the top of the fraction , because the first resistor is the equivalent one,with 2/5k ohms and the second one is 2k ohms.The theorem says:Vacross=Vin*(R2/(R1+R2)).

Comment: Hey , equivalent resistance is 2/5 not 2. So that is why I take it

Comment: Let's move this discussion to chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25812/discussion-between-on-the-way-to-success-and-daniel-tork).